# Confusion about a problem from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, holder-spaces

[Hölder Condition Implying Uniform Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36773/h%c3%b6lder-condition-implying-uniform-convergence)

I'm also working on Problem 5(b) from Chapter 3 in Stein's Complex Analysis(Page 110). In the discription of the problem, it assert that when some mild smoothness condition (such as Hölder Condition) is imposed on  $ h(x)$ , which is continuous and supported in $ [-k,k]$ , then $g(x_0+i\epsilon)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-k}^k \frac{h(x)}{x-(x_0+i\epsilon)}dx$ can converge to some function $ g_+(x_0) $  as $ \epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$ uniformly on  $ x_0\in[-k,k]$.

I may find a counterexample  to  the above argument. If assuming that $ h(x)=1$ on $ [-k,k]$ , it certainly satisfies Hölder condition. However by definition of $g(z)$,
$g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-k}^k \frac{h(x)}{x-z}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-k}^k \frac{1}{x-z}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi i}log\left(\frac{k-z}{k+z}\right)$, and it seems that $log\left(\frac{k-z}{k+z}\right)$ has singularities at $z=\pm k $,
$g(x_0+i\epsilon)$  can not converge to a unbouded function uniformly on  $ x_0\in[-k,k]$.

Do I miss something? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure that $1$ satisfies the condition "supported in $[-k,k]$" as that usually implies $h(x) \to 0, x \to \pm k$ for continuous $h$

Comment: @Conrad   good point. But I can't figure out how this may help to solve the "uniform convergence" problem. Can you give me more hints, thanks.

Comment: why don't you look at $|g(x+i\epsilon)-g(y+i\epsilon)|, x,y \in [-k,k]$, use the integral formula and the Holder condition and see what happens when $|x-y|$ small enough (it should be uniformly small so ensuring that $g(x+i\epsilon)$ is uniformly Cauchy hence uniformly convergent on the compact interval $[-k,k]$)

Comment: @Conrad thanks, I will try in that direction.   I have come up with anoter idea, but not sure it's a right direction. We know $g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-k}^k \frac{h(x)}{x-z}dx$ is holomorphic hence continuous in $ {\mathbb{C}}$ except $[-k,k]$. If $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$ exists for all $x_0\in[-k,k]$, it means $g(z)$ can be extended up to  $[-k,k]$.

Comment: @Conrad  So, if we can show that the $g(z)$ is continuous on a compact set in $ {\mathbb{C}}$, which includes $[-k,k]$ (e.g. rectangle with vertexes $k, k+i, -k+i, -k$), then the "uniform convergence" of $g(x_0+i\epsilon)$ (as $ \epsilon\rightarrow 0 $) can be proved by uniform continuity of $g(z)$ on the compact set. Is this a promising way?

Comment: $g$ doesn't extend continuously to $[-k,k]$ - the fact that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$ exists means that there is an extension from above and similarly one from below but they differ precisely by $h$ as the problem asks you to prove, so $g$ doesn't extend continuously (that is also trivial from general principles as then $g$ would be entire and that is not possible unless $h=g=0$); note that this is the same behavior as the logarithm or roots etc

Comment: @Conrad sorry for the ambiguity,  You are right, $g(z)$ is globally multiple-valued and "jump" by $h$ when across $[-k,k]$, which can be proved by Poisson kernel integral. What I try to do is to treat the convergence of $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$ separetly, i.e. from the above ($\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$) and from the below ($\lim_{\epsilon \to 0-}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$).

Comment: @Conrad  Such as, in the case of $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$, if $g(z)$ can be extended locally to a continuous function  on closed rectangle $(k, k+i, -k+i, -k)$, the "uniform convergence" of  $g(x_0+iϵ)$ to $g_+(x)$ can be shown (as $ϵ→0_+$). Is it true if $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0_+}g(x_0+i\epsilon)$ exists(i.e. $g_+(x)$),  $g(z)$ can be locally extended to a single-valued function on the above rectangle?

Comment: @Conrad  If it is right, my task will be to prove it's also continuous on the rectangle.

Comment: Uniform convergence is in general stronger than simple continuity at the boundary; see point a of the problem where you still have convergence and continuity at the boundary for continuous $h$ which may be wild

Comment: @Conrad Yes. According to part (a) of the problem, if $h(x)$ is continuous function on $R$,  then $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}g(x_0+i\epsilon)-g(x_0-i\epsilon)$ does exist, actaully equal to $h(x)$. But it does not mean either the $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}g(x_0+i\epsilon) $ or the  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}g(x_0-i\epsilon) $ exists. This is why Hölder Condition is introduced in part (b).

Comment: @Conrad  If $g(x+iy):=g(x,y)$ is a continuous function on rectangle $[-k,k]\times[0,1]$, the "uniform convergence" can be proved, it is actually a real analysis fact: $g(x,\epsilon):=g(x+i\epsilon)\rightarrow g(x,i0) =:g(x+i0)$ uniformly on $[-k,k]$ as $\epsilon \to 0+$, using the **uniform continuity** of $g(z):=g(x,y)$ on the compact set $[-k,k]\times[0,1]$.